# Syntax error: expecting identifier before class. Line 1?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have no clue why this is happening? It says I have an error on line 1, but its exactly the same as my other classes...well starts the same way. HELP?! :(

```
package class {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;



    public class Shape1 extends Sprite {
        private var xSpeed:int = 4;
        private var ySpeed:int = 4;


        public function Shape1(x,y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, drop);
        }

        protected function drop (e:Event){
            this.y += this.ySpeed;
            trace (this.y)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the `class` is a reserved word , don't use it as a package's name.

Read: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#class

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 'class'  keyword as a name for your package etc. Also you are missing a closing } parenthesis for package.